# Can "was" occur twice, consecutively, in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, doubled-words

Is this correct?:

"But I guess all there was was such a big lie."

I think I've heard that sentence in somewhere and it sounds to my ears just fine but wanted to make sure if it was still right.

(My question was closed before.)

Comment: That's a little awkward, but legit.

Comment: I'd add a comma after the first was

Comment: You said your previous question got closed. Was *was was* the topic of that question as well?

Comment: There's a Mavis Staples album called "If All I Was Was Black". Which appears grammatical to me.

Comment: As for was, was was never used in future tense.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence, "But I guess all there was was such a big lie," is grammatically correct. The accuracy of your sentence can be demonstrated by manipulating the noun phrase (NP) in the middle of your sentence. The NP *all there was* can be replaced by *it*, which results in the following sentence.

> But I guess *it* was such a big lie.

While your initial sentence may sound wrong due to a double word, the only issue is a clunky noun phrase. The structure of an NP is *(compliment) + noun + (compliment)*, and it functions as a single noun. Therefore, the phrase can be readily replaced by a single pronoun, and the flow of your sentence is resolved.

Ultimately, the only issue is flow, and the usage of two, consecutive *was* is completely acceptable in this context.